# Prevent MsgBox from overlapping existing alerts

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using `SetTimer()` to check for the presence of emails older than 1h in a particular mailbox, and show a `MsgBox()` alert advising me of such. The problem is that if I leave Outlook open overnight, I can come back to 20-30 overlapping `MsgBox()` alerts.

How do I constrain my program to only show one alert, and not continue displaying more alerts until the currently shown `MsgBox()` is dismissed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just setting a flag if you have an open alert? The next time the timer elapses, you check for the flag and do nothing. Once the user closes your alert, you reset your flag.

**EDIT**:
A slight optimization is to just stop the timer just before you show the first alert. Once the alert is confirmed by the user you restart your timer. That way you even get to save some CPU.

That way you prevent multiple alerts.
Am I missing something?

Comment: No, not missing anything. I just thought VBA was smart enough to not overlap message boxes endlessly. I'll go with one of your proposed solutions instead. Thanks.

Comment: I thought the same when I came across this problem in another language some time ago :D